# Manual Prettify does not work for "js" but "javascript" works

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Manual Prettify does not work for "js" but "javascript" works

```
<!-- language: js -->
```

got rendered as language "default", but

```
<!-- language: javascript -->
```

properly rendered as "lang-js"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags will now honor synonyms in the next deploy.